# Cannot use database tables after reinstalling wampserver

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have just reinstalled WAMPSERVER without backing-up the data folder of MYSQL under WAMPSERVER, with the understanding that uninstalling and re-installing WAMPSERVER would leave the data directory of MYSQL intact as it is. This was a re-installation of the same WAMPSERVER version.

So now I login to MYSQL, can see all databases and tables from previous WAMPSERVER using `SHOW DATABASES`, and `SHOW TABLES IN myDb`. But trying `SHOW COLUMNS IN myTable` or further attempt to access the data in these  tables fails, giving the error:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'myDb.myTable' doesn't exist
```

and the logfile:

```
2013-10-08 14:42:23 1072 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table myDB/myTable from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
```

Comment: I would try to export the tables, completely reinstall, then import them back

Comment: Did you find a solution meanwhile ?

Answer (score 0):

try an CREATE if not exists query, see what output this gives.